# Using Laravel 5 Method Injection with other Parameters

Tags: php, controller, routes, laravel-5

So I'm working on an admin interface. I have a route set up like so:

```
Route::controllers([
    'admin' => 'AdminController',
]);
```

Then I have a controller with some methods:

```
public function getEditUser($user_id = null)
{
    // Get user from database and return view
}

public function postEditUser($user_id = 0, EditUserRequest $request)
{
    // Process any changes made
}
```

As you can see, I'm using method injection to validate the user input, so URL's would look like this:

```
http://example.com/admin/edit-user/8697
```

A GET request would go to the GET method and a POST request to the POST method.  The problem is, if I'm creating a new user, there won't be an ID:

```
http://examplecom/admin/edit-user/
```

Then I get an error (paraphrased):

> Argument 2 passed to controller must be an instance of EditUserRequest, none given

So right now I'm passing an ID of 0 in to make it work for creating new users, but this app is just getting started, so am I going to have to do this throughout the entire application? Is there a better way to pass in a validation method, and optionally, parameters?  Any wisdom will be appreciated.

Comment: You should probably create another method for the create of the user. PUT should be used for update while POST should be used for create so: `putEditUser` and `postCreateUser`

Comment: What about if you reverse the order? `postEditUser(EditUserRequest $request, $user_id = null)`

Comment: @lukasgeiter Huh, I thought I tried that already, but it works like a charm (reversing the order). Post that as an answer and I'll accept it. Also, another method I was using was to just pass in the user_id as a hidden field, and have no user_id parameter on the POST method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reverse the order of your parameters so the optional one is a the end:

```
public function postEditUser(EditUserRequest $request, $user_id = null)
{

}
```

Laravel will then resolve the `EditUserRequest` first and pass nothing more if there's no user_id so the default value will kick in.